# How does gmail composing text area recognize html format?

Tags: html, formatting, gmail

If you copy some text from a webpage and paste it into gmail's composing box, it will recognize its format and render it accordingly. But if you type some html code in a text editor like:

```
<b>bold text here!</b>
```

and then paste it into gmail, it will render it verbatim. So my questions are:

1. How does this format recognition work?
2. How can I make gmail to recognize the pasting of html source code also?

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is Google's "web clipboard" which recognizes and preserves formatting when copying and pasting between web pages and gmail edit windows as well as google docs.  You can not get the same effect by typing in raw html without first getting that HTML rendered in a browser window.